# Rename errors on crashlitics

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics

I have a project where all errors and warnings were written in logs in classes where they occurred. I started to use crashlytics. And tried to combine all the logic connected to logging and errors to a specific class. And force this class to decide where to report an error (error + warning) and where to log warnings. But when I made it I started to receive all the errors as they have occurred in this class. Is it possible to rename errors? For example, manually add activity name in the report so I will get different errors and not the same error all the time. Not like on the picture.

[image: Firebase console screenshot]

```
    class AppLogs {
        companion object CrashReport {
            private fun reportToCrashlytics(
                errorMessage: String,
                user: String = "user id",
                log: String = "log",
                additionalInfoTitle: String = "title",
                additionalInfoMessage: String = " message"
            ) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(log)
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId(user)
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()
                    .setCustomKey(additionalInfoTitle, additionalInfoMessage)
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(throw Exception(errorMessage))
            }
    
            private fun reportLog(errorMessage: String) {
                Timber.e(errorMessage)
            }
    
            fun report(errorMessage: String, errorType: Char) {
                if (errorType == 'e') {
                    reportLog(errorMessage)
                    reportToCrashlytics(errorMessage)
                } else {
                    reportLog(errorMessage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer for the actual issue

> ... manually add activity name in the report so I will get different errors and not the same error all the time ...

The answer is short - no it is not possible (without enormous effort).

#### But why?

Crashlytics uses the stack trace of the throwable object which was reported. Using this stack allows us to get reports that track the exception right to the line where it occurred.

It means that to create another issue record in the list of issues you have to modify the stack trace of the throwable object.

[`TrimmedThrowableData`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/296aa4fe9f78528ccfb846747e050e2e67a9ef5a/firebase-crashlytics/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/crashlytics/internal/stacktrace/TrimmedThrowableData.java#L31) is the class that collects stack trace data to report. As you can see it gets unmodified stack trace of the throwable.

**Most likely the only solution**

If you want to get different stack trace - create `Exception` objects where `reportToCrashlytics` is used and pass these objects as arguments. Or throw and catch exceptions, and report exceptions that were caught.

---

## Previous answer (bug found)

You are throwing the exception making the application crash. You should create `Exception` object and just pass it in as an argument.

If you open IDE you will see that the line where `throw` is used has `recordException` method highlighted and if you hover a cursor over it you will see the following:

[image: The warning from IDE]

It means that you never execute `recordException` because arguments are evaluated first and then passed into the function. But the function is never reached because `throw` crashes the application.

Do not use `throw` keyword:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(Exception(errorMessage))
```

Comment: This is not really helps me with my problem, but thanks.

Comment: @KeitL, I misunderstood the issue initially. I thought your app crashes every time it tries to log the error and thus you get crash logs that are located in `CrashReport`. I'll update my answer but the short answer to your problem is - no, it is not possible to set an activity name or similar information. I'll explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can change Your Stack trace like this :

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

public CustomException(String message, int lineNumber) {
    super(message);
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = getStackTrace();
    StackTraceElement[] newStackTrace = new StackTraceElement[stackTrace.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(stackTrace, 0, newStackTrace, 1, stackTrace.length);
    newStackTrace[0] = new StackTraceElement("className", "methodName", "fileName", lineNumber);
    setStackTrace(newStackTrace);
}
}
```